# How to specify constant data wrt cache coherence?

Tags: caching, c++11

I am suspecting cache latency issues due to constant data (or same data across multiprocessor caches) being churned up in the cache coherence protocols. Is there a way to specify specific data as constant so as to avoid snooping or such messages being passed around caches for that data?

Comment: Typically, this snooping is done as part of writing to memory.  Multiple reading processors should be ok, as long as your data lives in a cache line that has no writing (or at most one writing processor).  A large table that is only read and not written should be fine for multiple processor usage.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_snooping).

Comment: Also, see [global-initialized-variables-declared-as-const-go-to-text-segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954403/global-initialized-variables-declared-as-const-go-to-text-segment-while-those), as putting data into the text segment will ensure both that it cannot be written, and that it doesn't mingle with data that may be written.